# C# Console App executable (.exe) does not save updated file to disk

Tags: c#, debugging, console-application, exe

I have a very simple C# console application that copies a specific node from an existing XML file located on my computer to another XML file, also located on my computer. I've hardcoded the paths in an app.config file within the solution.

When I debug my solution (F5) the files get updated appropriately. However, if I run without debugging (Control+F5) or if I build (or publish) to bin/Release or bin/Debug and run the my-console-app.exe the application fails to save any file to disk.

Strangely this app used to work without issue (it was used in conjunction with a .bat file which called it and deployed the updated configuration file to a server). But over the last few weeks I've noticed this console app has seemingly worked less and less over time to the point where to get my update script to run successfully I have to open this console application's solution, press F5, then run my .bat script.

I've used ProcessMonitor by sysinternals to verify that files are being read/written and it says that files are being written to the file paths that I'm specifying, however when I browse to the directory the file doesn't not exist or is not updated.

I'm using VS2010 on a Mac Mini running Windows 7 Ultimate via Bootcamp.

TL;DR; Console app works and updates files appropriately when debugging but not when run without debugging or as a standalone or published .exe from bin/Release, etc.

```
var devConfig = XDocument.Load(DevConfigPath, LoadOptions.None);
var prodConfig = XDocument.Load(ProductionConfigPath, LoadOptions.None);

var devMethods = devConfig.Descendants("deliveryMethods");
prodConfig.Root.Element("Heg.EA.Delivery").Element("deliveryMethods").ReplaceWith(devMethods);
try
{
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Dev First Node:{0}", devConfig.Root.Element("ClientDeliveryTest").Element("deliveryMethods").FirstNode.ToString())); // Test Node to ensure file is being read correctly (it is).
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Production First Node:{0}", prodConfig.Root.Element("Heg.EA.Delivery").Element("deliveryMethods").FirstNode.ToString())); // Test Node to ensure production configuration is updated correctly (it is).

Console.WriteLine("Saving...");
prodConfig.Save(@"C:\ProductionConfig.config"); // FAIL.
prodConfig.Save(@"ProductionConfig.config"); // FAIL.
prodConfig.Save(ProductionConfigPath); // FAIL.
Console.Write("File Saved.");
}
catch (Exception ex) // No exception is ever thrown.
{
Console.Write(String.Format("Error Saving: {0}", ex));
}
```

Comment: Is there any chance you're starting VS with different rights than when starting the application individually, and that this somehow influences saving to `C:\`?

Comment: Root of C, is not a good place. File may be redirected to virtualstore, e.g. C:\Users\MyUser \AppData\Local\VirtualStore\ProductionConfig.config.

Comment: Not only that, but windows will generally deny write permission there outright unless launched as an administrator.

Comment: I've tried explicity running the console app as Administrator with no luck. I've also tried                 prodConfig.Save(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)) + @"\ConfigurationUtility\ProductionConfig.config");

Comment: If DevConfigPath or ProductionConfigPath are pointing to C:\ then the XDocument.Load may be throwing an exception as, unless you are running as an administrator, you may not have permission to access files in the root. As this code is outside your try/catch, you wont hit the Console.Write - it's effectively unhandled. You've done exactly the right thing with Process Monitor so it's a bit strange.

Comment: I'm actually able to READ the files without issue. When I run my test app, I'm able to copy the specific node from the development config file to the production config file. However, when prodConfig.Save() is called, no data is ever actually written no matter what the path is...unless I'm debugging, then it works fine.

Comment: I've also made sure the framework is set to .NET 4 and not Client Profile. Also ticked off ClickOnce Security and Manifests checkboxes from the Signing and Security tabs from the solution properties. No changes in behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. I uploaded my solution to my work repository and had my boss check it out. He was able to open it, build it, debug it, and run the exe from bin/Release. However, when he ran the exe, Avast popped up with a friendly message, denying him access, which he remedied and the program execution continued.

I also have Avast. It never prompted me to allow/disallow my app from executing or writing to disk. But I went to the avast options and disabled the AutoSandbox feature and everything worked.

TL;DR; Antivirus settings prevented my console app from writing to disk and didn't prompt me about it.